# Make tailwind overflow just for the child

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

So I was trying to create a dashboard for a side project and I want to create a scrollable part where the user can search/filter some results.

The project is in tailwind and svelte.

So here's the issue, if I have more results than what can fit on a page, the div overflows, which is fine but the problem is that the entire div overflows instead of the part with more elements than needed.

This is a playground with the full code [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/), please make the window with the results bigger.

The  is bigger than the div that overflows and the parent div is then scrollable when just the ul should be

```
<div class="h-full">
<section class="bg-[#F1F6FA] h-full   p-4">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-screen-xl  h-full">
        <div
            class=" overflow-y-auto h-full lg:grid lg:grid-cols-4  lg:items-start lg:gap-8"
        >
            <div
                class="hidden space-y-4 h-full overflow-y-scroll  bg-white rounded-md p-4  border shadow-md lg:block"
            >


                <div>
                    <p class="block text-xs font-medium text-gray-700">
                        Filters
                    </p>

                    <div class="mt-1 space-y-2">
  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lg:col-span-3 ">
                <div class="relative mb-4">
  
                </div>

                <ul class="overflow-y-auto">
                    <li>

                    </li>
                    
                    <li>

                    </li>

                    <li>

                    </li>
                </ul>


                <ol class="flex justify-center gap-1 mt-4 text-xs font-medium">

     
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

</div>
```

Comment: You have `h-full` which applies `height: 100%`, but unless the element is a descendent that can resolves to a concrete height, this does nothing. Perhaps provide more of the parent ancestral code. Also, you seemed to have forgotten to include your Tailwind Play code – you have linked to `https://play.tailwindcss.com/` instead of the unique URL for your code.